# Why are my s.prop variable instances not getting updated properly in SiteCatalyst?

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I have this weird problem in Sitecatalyst where I am unable to account for about 50% of my traffic recored via props. I update the s.pageName and a s.prop1 with same values before making the s.t() call. I get equal total values in the Pages report and the Page Views , but when I check the prop1 variable report, i have close to 50% of the traffic missing. I am at a loss to figure out why the traffic is missing, any help from Omniture developers would be appreciated.

I am using a dictionary to iterate over the props/variable and their values that need to be set.

```
var paramsMap = {
        "pageName": "pageName",
        "pageType": "prop1" }, 
    params = {
        "pageName":"mysite - demopage",
        "pageType":"demopage"};

for (var key in params)
        s[paramsMap[key]] = params[key];
```

Comment: At face value there's no reason they shouldn't line up. The only reasons I can think of that this would happen is if prop1 isn't popping every time an `s.t` call is made, or if you're not looking at the same date ranges or have a filter or segment in place when looking at `prop1` report, or maybe the date range doesn't line up for when you implemented `prop1`, or some similar scenario.

Comment: you can contact clientcare and request a raw logs dump for the date range and see if prop1 is in fact included in all the s.t calls. Other ways `prop1` could be getting suppressed: do you have any processing rules in place that would overwrite it with an empty value or similar? Any VISTA rules in place that may be overwriting it?

Comment: no VISTA rules, and there are no processing rules either .. s.pageName and s.prop1 are set at the same time with the same variable value. I will try the log dumps route

Comment: Make sure you're using the page view metric in the prop report. Also, post the code of how you set the variables if you can and check if that prop runs though the getvalonce plugin in the scode.

Comment: added code snippet above. I have setup the report to show Page Views as well as Instance views but the total of the Page views does not add up with the toal on the Pages report. I even set s.debugTracking=true to see if the values are getting set, and I could see the c1(i assume thats what prop1 refers to) is getting set properly in the console.

Comment: c1 is indeed the URL request variable for prop1. Have you checked if the error is related to only some browsers, or if it is the same across the board? This is usually what I confirm first in situations like this.